# Replace all variations of a string regardless of comma position Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a data frame that consists of multiple rows that contain different variations of a string that is separated by commas. Rather than constantly writing variations of this code such as `df.replace('Word,', '')`, I am looking for a simpler way to replace variations in strings for python. I have heard about regex yet am having a difficult time understanding it.

One such example that I am looking into is `df.column.str.replace('Word,?', '')` which would replace all variations of "Word" regardless of comma position. However, I am unsure as to how this works. Any help in understanding replacing using regex would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Example:

```
'Word, foo, bar'         
'Word'   
'foo, bar, Word'  
'foo, Word, bar'
```

Desired Output:

```
'foo, bar'   
''        
'foo, bar'           
'foo, bar'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as below
**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Word, foo, bar'],
                   [2, 'Word'],
                   [3, 'foo, bar, Word'],
                   [4, 'foo, Word, bar']],columns=['id', 'text'])

id  text
1   Word, foo, bar
2   Word
3   foo, bar, Word
4   foo, Word, bar
```

Code to replace text 'Word' and following comma & space if any

```
df['text']=df['text'].replace('Word(,\s)|(,\s)?Word','',regex=True)
```

What is happening in the code

`Word` : will search for the text 'Word'

`(,\s)?` : will look for comma`,` followed by space`\s`, `?` will look and match if it is available, if comma & space does not follow, then just the text 'Word' is matched. So `?` is pretty important here.

`|` : this matches one of the 2 expressions (in your case this is needed for line 3 where there is a preceding space & comma)

You can see detailed explanation here [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kMcMD2/2)

**Output**

```
id  text
1   foo, bar
2   
3   foo, bar
4   foo, bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution I am giving you the answer for the solution due to the link that was provided. Regex is a problem that I am having difficulty in understanding and that link is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.replace(to_replace='Word,|(, )?Word',value='',regex=True)
```

This way `.replace()` method will do the required work.

`to_replace` is our regular expression criteria and it should be in string.
`'Word,'` will match all strings except at the end in form of `", Word"`.

To match those end string we provided `"|"(or)` so that we can add new criteria which is `"(, )?Word"`. Here `?` match 0 or 1 occurrence of `", "`(comma and 1 space) so that both conditions for ending string as well as only 1 string `"Word"` matched

`Value = ''` : which show what to be replaced with

`regex = True` : which tells to treat `"to_replace"` parameter as a regex expression